# Visual Studio 2015 issues after downloading ASP.NET 5 RC 1

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

After downloading the Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 (ASP.NET 5 RC 1), I am no longer able to see project templates and opening an existing project causes Visual Studio to crash.

[image]

Any one else experiencing the same or have any suggestions?

Cheers.

Comment: As far as I know update 1 for vs 2015 will be released nov 30. Asp.net 5 rc1 is a separate thing and a separate download from http://get.asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Try that: **Tools -> Import and Export Settings Wizard -> Reset all settings**

Answer (score 0):

You can try to repair your VisualStudio

go to programm and features and look for Microsoft Visual Studio[image]